# Hidden Button when run form

Tags: winforms, user-controls, devexpress

I designed a form using user-control
[image]

But when run the form the buttons are lost. I don't know. 
[image]

Comment: It appears the form may be covering up the buttons. It is difficult to determine why this is without seeing how you are creating the form. If you are using the designer, then select the buttons and click the `BringToFront` button. If you are creating the form programmatically, then check to see if the buttons are added BEFORE you place the grid on the form.

Comment: I do not understand why. The first time I designed this form it ran pretty well. Starting 2 weeks before I was vegetarian, it was like that

Comment: I could be wrong but I have not heard of any program changing simply because you choose not to eat meat. The two pictures look like TWO different forms. Are you creating this form in the “Designer” or programatically?

Comment: Oh no, Is one form! :'(

Comment: I hate to disagree, but the two pictures are two different forms. The second picture is missing the “User Sign” and ‘User Sign 2” labels along with their text boxes. In addition, the bottom grid appears to span the whole tab page horizontally and vertically. Those are two different forms unless you are doing something after the form is initialized.

Comment: You do not know the hidden field???

Comment: You are right I do not know the hidden field. Apparently, your question is missing important information. Showing your code is the proper protocol to help you solve your dilemma. You may want to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that shows how SO works. In addition, you may want to peruse, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also if you need [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: You have to correct Anchor property of the buttons (it's set to "Top, Left" now)

Comment: I did, but did not

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using DevExpress [LayoutControl](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/layout/) to create such a layout. This way, your controls will be automatically positioned/resized and properly displayed regardless your form size, screen resolution, DPI settings, etc. 
If you button is not visible because of the form size, LayoutControl will show a vertical scrollbar.